# How to get nodes and topics without ros running

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I tried to get my head arround how to best solve this problem but I'm probably missing a simple solution.
i have a ros workspace. In this workspace I have multiple packages. And in each package I have probably multiple ros nodes.

Now what I want to do is I want to write a script that can get my all the nodes and possibly also all the publishers  subscribers. Also if possible the parameters and services .

One idea of me was getting all the packages via the  **rospack list | workspace_name**
and that also works great to get the packages in the workspace.

But now the problem is how to I get all the publishers /subscribers. I know that I could get them online if the node is running via the rosnode command but how should I do this offline.

I hope I just overlooked something, I hope someone could help me what the offline methode for this is.

For additional information I'm working on ros Kinetic on  Ubuntu 16.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296228/how-to-get-nodes-and-topics-without-ros-running/) by [Lycea](https://answers.ros.org/users/36240/lycea/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2018-07-04

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2018-07-04**:
Why do you want to do that ? Being "offline" means that you don't initialize your nodes and publishers/subscribers and everything else so you won't be able to find anything.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-07-05**:
I second the comment by @Delb: it would be good if you can provide some more context. Perhaps easier alternatives or more suitable approaches exist for what your ultimate goal is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think grep is your best option. Navigate to the `src` directory of your Catkin workspace to issue these commands.

List Python and C++ nodes:

```
grep -Er "rospy.init_node|ros::init"
```

List Python and C++ subscribers:

```
grep -Er "rospy.Subscriber|.subscribe\("
```

List Python and C++ publishers:

```
grep -Er "rospy.Publisher|.advertise<"
```

List Python and C++ services:

```
grep -Er "rospy.Service\(|.advertiseService\("
```

Note that this assumes in Python you always call things relative to `rospy`. For C++ you could also grep on `ros::Subscriber`, `ros::Publisher`, and `ros::ServiceServicer`, but I did it the way I did so you can account for when you have separate header and source files - the commands I provide pick up on where the actual definition is provided.

---

Originally posted by [adamconkey](https://answers.ros.org/users/27913/adamconkey/) with karma: 642 on 2018-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lycea](https://answers.ros.org/users/36240/lycea/) on 2018-08-07**:
Thank you for that answer that was  what I was searching for . I did it now in a kind of similar way to as you wrote. :)